# Bind multiple views to multiple viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have a WPF window displaying different self-defined Views. So far I was able to use everything I learned about MVVM :)

Now I got to a new "problem": I have 10 entities of the same view in a bigger view. These ten view-entities contain a set of controls (textbox, combobox etc.) but are all consistent.

So how do I bind these Views to a ViewModel?

I thought about having 10 instances of the ViewModel in the "higher-level" ViewModel and give the views fix-defined the instances of the VM as datacontext.

My question is now --> Is there a easier (or more convienient) way to bind many (identical) views to their viewmodels?

**Code-Example:**

View Model:

```
private PanelViewModel _panelViewModel1 = new PanelViewModel();
public PanelViewModel PanelVM1
{
   get { return _panelViewModel1; }
}
```

View-Example:

```
<myControls:vwPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="vwPanel1" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Path=PanelVM1}"/>
```

What bothers me is that I would need this logic ten times for ten views?

**UPDATE:**
To answer some questions: I want to show one view 10 times (in my example) I defined my own view by inheriting from UserControl. So my `vwPanel` inherits from `UserControl`. The 10 vwPanels are just placed inside a StackPanel inside a Grid.

It's not about displaying data, as you pointed out, there would be a listview or a datagrid a better place to start. It's a special case where I need this much input-controls :/

**UPDATE2:** What I hoped for was more like defining a List of ViewModels and Bind my 10 Views to one of this List. But this will not work will it? At least I wouldn't know how to refernce one "special" entitiy in the list out of XAML...

Comment: Are the ten views in the bigger view specially defined? In other words, is there any reason why you can't, say, create a List and bind that List to an IEnumerable of your ViewModels and have them displayed that way?

Comment: @Tim I need them in correct order to have in- and output in the correct order. Would this be possible without having them specially-defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically I use implicit `DataTemplates` for mapping `Views` to `ViewModels`. They can go in `<Application.Resources>`, `<Window.Resources>` or even in under specific elements only such as `<TabControl.Resources>`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PanelViewModel}">
    <myControls:vwPanel />
</DataTemplate>
```

This means that anytime WPF encounters an object in the VisualTree of type `PanelViewModel`, it will draw it using `vwPanel`

Objects typically get placed in the `VisualTree` through an `ItemsSource` property

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfAllPanels}" />
```

or by using a `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PanelVM1}" />
```

Comment: But what I still be able to "identify" these? I mean in MVVM you have the order V->VM->M. Would my views know their correct VM using your solution? Especially if the Properties in the VM get changed by theri higher-level VM?

Comment: @chiffre, the order that the VMs show up in your itemsControl is the exact order that they're added to the ItemsSource collection. So, using Rachel's example, if you add 3 viewmodels to "Panels", they'll display in the order you add them. When you select the first one, and change a property on it, then the viewmodel in index 0 of Panels will have that property changed. As for notifying the view when your higher-level VM changes another VM, as long as your VM implements INotifyPropertyChanged correctly, you'll be alright.

Comment: @chiffre I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. From my understanding, your VM contains 10 `PanelViewModel` properties that you want to display using the exact same `Panel` UserControl. Depending on how your panels are listed in the VM, you can either display them using something like an `ItemsControl` (if they are stored in an `ObservableCollection`), or a `ContentControl` (if they are stored in 10 separate properties). The `DataContext` behind the `PanelUserControl` will be whatever `PanelViewModel` its bound to, so yes they will display the correct data when updated by the parent VM

Comment: Now I think I understood what you mean! This could actually work - I will try it out later on with different ItemControls etc, because I will need to have them automatically collapse and so on. So I will have to figure out what to use. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a collection of something that you what to represent visually. That is, you have several viewmodels that you want to define a single view for, but show X number of times. Your example shows you using a panel as your view for the "PanelViewModel"...what is the parent item's control for the vwPanel? Assuming you're using something like a ListBox, you can define a custom DataTemplate that contains your vwPanel and assign that DataTemplate to your ListBox.ItemTemplate.

For example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myVMTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type myViewModels:PanelViewModel}">
        <myControls:vwPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollectionOfPanelVMs}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myVMTemplate}" />
```

I haven't verified that this works.